# ReactJS: Render a private image asset from S3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am using NodeJS backend API server that allows the frontend (ReactJS / React Native) to upload an image using form-data. This is the code I am using:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "us-east-1",
});

...

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    acl: 'private',
    metadata(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '.png');
    }
  })
})

...

app.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.file)
})
```

The API server works as it should and the image is uploaded in a private secured bucket using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

However now I want to be able to render this image on ReactJS or React Native. Do you recommend building another NodeJS route called something like `/render` and somehow stream it to the backend? If yes, how can I do it?

Alternatively, should I render it directly from the frontend and risking exposing the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` keys to the user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a number of trial and errors, I found out that the most elegant solution is to have NodeJS to take care of the communication with S3. The frontend will then `GET` the image from NodeJS through a route which can be done as follows:

```
  app.get("/image/:imageId", function(req, res, next) {
    var params = { Bucket: keys.AWS_BUCKET, Key: req.params.imageId };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({ error: err });
      }
      res.send(data.Body);
    });
  });
```

Why do I think that this is more elegant than the solution proposed by *luboskmac*?

For starters, I am not exposing the asset to the public at no point in time. I am only revealing the NodeJS `GET` route to the end user.

Secondly, if I wanted to restrict access to this route, I can simply use `passportJS` inside NodeJS to, for example, restrict access to the asset to only logged in users. This is useful in many scenarios, such as in the case of GDPR requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Solution is simple:

1. Randomize S3 URLs, so that they are not guessable (e.g. use UUIDs)
2. Make these assets public
3. Make all S3 folders private, so that if user in one browser have URL to certain asset, he/she can't list contents of S3 folders above.

This way, users would be able to access only assets you send them from server + without AWS API keys (sending keys to browser would be huge security flaw)

This is very same concept e.g. Google Docs, Dropbox uses when you share a link and send it to somebody. Everybody in the world would be able to read that link, but if link is not guessable, asset can be accessed only if you share that link.

Answer (score 0):

Making the bucket public is not recommended due to privacy and security concerns, use [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws) instead.